# How to deal with Non-Linear prediction intervals with horizontal asymptotes?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, prediction-interval

I'm using a weibull regression on a data set which reports % total expenditures over time. Time is measured by % of project total completed, therefore neither the dependent or independent variable can be below 0 or exceed 1.

I'm attempting to find a way to interpret the prediction interval that my software gives me, and I'm wondering what the best approach would be.

It uses the following prediction interval formula for non-linear curves:

$t_{\alpha/2}$ * SE * (1+$z_o$$(Z'Z)^{-1}$$z_o$')$^{1/2}$

This formula, unsurprisingly, gives predictions that are out of range. Do I simply restrict the domain of the high and low prediction curve to that which gives intelligible results, or is the prediction completely wrong and I should ignore the software, choosing a different method instead?